# chipmunk physics make static platform move

Tags: ios, chipmunk

I have some static platforms which are not added to space - cpBodyNew(INFINITY, INFINITY) and some dynamic boxes with mass and moment which are added to space. When I need to move only static platforms I have very strange behaviour of dynamic bodies. It looks like they are trying to remain at the same place. This is how I move them:

```
 body.->p = cpv(newX, newY);
```

I tried to apply forces, but static bodies are not added to space, so it doesn't work. Then I tried to make add static bodies to space, then they fall down because of gravity. So now I don't know what to do with this bodies.